# Config VirtualHosts on Debian/Apache

Tags: apache, debian

On my debian/apache server at http://localhost I'm redirected to my api on port 3000 (this is ok)
Now I would like to open another port (8090), in http://localhost:8090 redirected to /var/www/html/

How to make?

Answer (score 0):

Find the default virtual host conf file by running

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

There should be a file called deault.conf, or similar. We want to edit this file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

Make sure that apache actually is listening to your port 8090 by adding, to the top of that document

```
Listen 8090
```

Change the rest of the conf file to match your site, so it may look something like this

```
Listen 8090

<VirtualHost *:8090>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

  # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file with a different name in the same folder. The files must end with ".conf". Add the virtual host to enabled sites by running

```
sudo a2ensite virtual_host_file_name.conf
```

replacing "virtual_host_file_name.conf" with the name of the file you select in the previous step.

Then restart the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

It seems like you're only interested in accessing it from localhost, but if you want to access it remotely you might need to check your firewalls.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working. But I have another question if you can help. I have access to port 8890 at http: // localhost: 8890, http://127.0.0.1:8890 and 192.168.xx.xx: 8890 (via mobile). Although I can access my api (postgrest) on port 3000 on both localhost: 3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 I can not access external on 192.168.15.xx: 3000. Why?

Comment: Check your router that the ports are open. Also run `ufw status` to see if the firewall on Debian is active. If it is active you must run `sudo ufw allow 8890` to open that port. Also, please mark my answer as accepted if you feel it answered your original question :-)

Comment: ufw is active and allow for 3000, but I can not access it yet .... I did not understand how to configure the router!

Comment: Find your router producer and model, google that along with "open port" or "port forwarding". Most likely you will find step-by-step instructions for your router.

Comment: It struck me that 192.168.15.xx  looks like an internal IP. So just to be sure, if you wish to connect to your server outside your house, you must use your public ip: https://www.myip.com.